# Adding offset to timestamp in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe df and when I run print(df.index), I get:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2011-08-05 00:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 01:00:00-04:00',
               '2011-08-05 02:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 03:00:00-04:00',
               '2011-08-05 04:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 05:00:00-04:00',
               '2011-08-05 06:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 07:00:00-04:00',
               '2011-08-05 08:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 09:00:00-04:00',
               ...
               '2017-07-30 14:00:00-04:00', '2017-07-30 15:00:00-04:00',
               '2017-07-30 16:00:00-04:00', '2017-07-30 17:00:00-04:00',
               '2017-07-30 18:00:00-04:00', '2017-07-30 19:00:00-04:00',
               '2017-07-30 20:00:00-04:00', '2017-07-30 21:00:00-04:00',
               '2017-07-30 22:00:00-04:00', '2017-07-30 23:00:00-04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', name=u'Time', length=52488, freq=None)
```

I am trying to modify the datetimeindex object, so that the

1. First timestamp in the series is changed from `'2011-08-05 00:00:00-04:00'` to `'2011-08-04 20:00:00'` and
2. Second stamp in the series would be changed from `'2011-08-05 00:00:00-04:00'` to `'2011-08-04 21:00:00'`, and so on.

I tried `pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`, but it returns the same `datetimeindex` object as above.

It is OK with me if the timestamps are converted to string, so I tried:

```
df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But neither lines of code achieves my end goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert.html) for remove `timezone`s and add `Hour`s:

```
df.index.tz_convert(None) + pd.offsets.Hour(16)
```

Or:

```
df.index.tz_convert(None) + pd.Timedelta(16, unit='h')
```

Sample:

```
idx = ['2011-08-05 00:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 01:00:00-04:00', 
       '2011-08-05 02:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 03:00:00-04:00']
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(idx).tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('America/New_York')
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2011-08-05 00:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 01:00:00-04:00',
               '2011-08-05 02:00:00-04:00', '2011-08-05 03:00:00-04:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, America/New_York]', freq=None)

idx = idx.tz_convert(None) + pd.offsets.Hour(16)
print (idx)
DatetimeIndex(['2011-08-05 20:00:00', '2011-08-05 21:00:00',
               '2011-08-05 22:00:00', '2011-08-05 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='H')
```